# Elasticsearch JSON query based on URL query

Tags: php, database, elasticsearch, nosql

Could someone tell me how to write in JSON query which will correspond to cURL query : `/indice/type/_search?q=hardskill:1AND21ANDsoftskill:5`

I want find docs which have hardskill [1,21], softskill [5].

Config looks like

```
type => [hardskill : [1,2,3,4..], softskill[1,2,3,5..]]
```

Pseudo code :

```
"query" => [
   "hardskill" : [1,21],
   "softskill:  [5]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
      "range" : {
          "hardskill" : {
              "gte" : 1,
              "lt" :  21
          }
      },
      "softskill" : 5
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-range-query.html

Answer (score 0):

The correct query DSL is the following one

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "hardskill": [1, 21]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "softskill": [5]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```